# Convert UTF-8 to ANSI in tcl

Tags: tcl

```
proc pub:write { nick host handle channel arg } {
set fid [open /var/www/test.txt w]
puts $fid "█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████"
puts $fid "██"
close $fid
}
```

when i open i Webbrowser its Result so :

```
 â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ
```

but it should :

```
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
```

Comment: You should read the documentation for the `fconfigure` command, especially the section on `-encoding`. Depending on how complex your problem is, you might want to read the documentation for the `encoding` command too, but that shouldn't be necessary. Tcl supports several encodings that could be labeled "ANSI", so your question is rather hard to answer as currently stated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the yawning pit of complexity that is string encodings. You've got to get *two* things right to make what you're trying to do work. ***READ EVERYTHING BELOW BEFORE MAKING CHANGES*** as it all interacts horribly.

1. The character needs to be written to the file using the right encoding. This is done by configuring the encoding on the channel, which defaults to a system-specific value that is usually *but not always* right.

   I'm taking a *very* wild guess that an encoding like “cp437 DOSLatinUS” is the right one.

   ```
   fconfigure $fid -encoding cp437
   ```

   However, Tcl's usually pretty good at picking the right thing to do by default.

   Also, there's a huge number of different encodings. Some are very similar to each other and picking which one to use is a bit of a black art. The usual best bet is to stick with `utf8` when possible, and otherwise to use the correct encoding (defined by protocol or by the system) and take a vast amount of care. *This is really complicated!*
2. You've *also* got to get the character into Tcl correctly in the first place. This means that the character has to be encoded in the source file, and Tcl has to read that file with the right encoding. Since the file is being written by another program (your editor usually) there's all sorts of potential for trouble. If you can discover what encoding is being used there (usually a matter of complete guesswork) then you can use the `-encoding` option to `tclsh` or `source` to allow Tcl to figure out what is going on.

   Alternatively, stick with the ASCII subset in your source as that's pretty reliably handled the same whatever encoding is in use. You do this by converting each `█` to the Tcl escape sequence `\u2588`. At least like that, you can be sure that you're *only* hunting down problems with the output encoding.

When debugging this thing, *only change one thing at a time* before retesting as there's a lot of bits that can go wrong and poison what is going on in ways that produce weird results downstream. I advise trying the escape sequence first as that at least means that you know that the input data is correct; once you know that you're not pushing garbage in, you can try hunting down whether you're actually getting problems with getting garbage out and what to do about it.

Finally, be aware that mixing in networking in this makes the problems about ten times harder…